# UWP applications Main method

Tags: c#, uwp

Like in WPF applications you can change the Build Action of App.xaml file properties to Page and you can write and customize the Main function(entry point) in App.xaml.cs. My question is how this can be done in UWP applications
currently my Application contains the Main function in obj file. My problem is to move my Main function in the App.xaml.cs rather than present in App.g.i.cs file.
Below attached is the image where the Main function gets automatically generated.

[image]

Comment: The App.g.i.cs file in a UWP is an automatically generated file based on the code in the App.xaml and App.xaml.cs files, if I remembre correctly.
What are you looking to achieve exactly in the main method?

Comment: Yes I know about App.g.i.cs file and how it gets generated I want to utilize let say I want to utilize the args array and many other things. @SharpNip